# What is the proper way to do element-wise operations on two vectors in the Spark model?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I'm using PySpark with YARN and have two RDD's, A & B that I wish to perform a chain of various, element-wise calculations on.  Both RDD's are vectors that are the same length and broken into the same number of partitions.  My current approach is as follows :

```
#C = A + B
C = A.zip(B).map(lambda x: x[0] + x[1])
```

When I call a collect on an RDD that is the result of a chain of 5-8 of these types of operations, I start to lose executors.  If I keep collecting further down the chain, enough executors will be lost to cause the calculation to fail.  Increasing the amount of memory per executor allows the calculation to finish. This prompts the following questions :

1. Is the A.zip(B).map(operation(A,B)) the intended method of operating on two RDD's?
2. Are there hidden pitfalls that I'm running into in using this method?  I read that executors may be lost due to excessive memory allocation on them. This wouldn't make sense to me as my interpretation of an RDD was simply as a set of instructions in making an intermediate data set, not the actual distributed data set itself.